# Plot: Stack bar with three columns

Tags: python, pandas, charts, bar-chart

I have below dataframe.

```
df = '''type    time    gender
0   A   660.0   M
1   B   445.0   M
2   C   68.0    M
3   A   192.2   F
4   B   82.9    F
'''
```

I use the below code plot above data.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.groupby(['gender','type']).count().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x:100*x / x.sum()
).unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.legend( prop={'size': 16})
plt.show()
```

My output:

[image]

Q: I want to plot these two bars with involving the time of the data.
Appreciate it if someone can help!

Comment: what do you mean `involving the time of the data`? Do you want the actual time on the `y` axis?

Comment: Yes. I want to plot bars with actual time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `matplotlib`, then

```
(df.pivot_table(index='gender', columns='type', 
               values='time', aggfunc='sum', 
               fill_value=0)
   .apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1)
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I scale y-axis 100%?

Comment: What do you mean `scale y-axis 100`? That's not your actual time any more, is it?

Comment: actual time. ex: F has only type A and B. But I want to show the ratio of the actual time in 100 scale.  I am sorry for my explaination

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted and could not achieve.